# NASM example throws memory violation

Tags: memory, nasm

I am new to NASM assembler, and would like to just compile a small example.

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
mov EAX,1
```

Compiling it with

```
$ nasm -f elf64 code.asm ; ld code.o ; ./a.out
Naruszenie ochrony pamięci (zrzut pamięci)
```

Building works fine but running yields memory access violation.

Comment: You don't terminate your program so it continues to execute code in memory until failure. You need to use the exit syscall to properly terminate

Comment: You should be able to add `mov eax, 60` followed by `syscall` to exit. You can set the value in _RDI_ prior to the exit syscall to return a particular value.

Comment: This worked for the example above. When applied to other codes I have it still throws the same error. Maybe I am doing something, but I got the gist of it, Thank you, and turn it into an answer if you like.